# It is possible to define an ansible.cfg file as the main config for only one role?

Tags: ansible

I would like to run the 'ssh' role without the become directive and run my others roles run with the become directive
I decided to create an another config file `ansible_ssh.cfg` which not contains the becomes statements, and attribute it to the ssh role

I tried this (in tasks/ssh.yml):

```
- name: deploiement clé ssh
  environment:
    ANSIBLE_CONFIG: ansible_ssh.cfg
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ansible_user_id}}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/{{ansible_user_id}}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

and that (at role level):

```
roles:
      - ssh
   environment:
     ANSIBLE_CONFIG: /var/lib/rundeck/ansible/roles:ssh/files/ansible_ssh.cfg
      - proxy
      - vmware_tools
      - ntp
      - nmap
      - tcpdump
      - unattended-upgrades
      - traceroute
      - apache
      - mysql
```

But without success

Ansible version: 2.7

Comment: Hi Ludo and welcome to StackExchange. Since it looks like 0xSheepdog's answer has solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" (the tick next to the answer) to help other users find the answer easier and give kudos to the author.

Answer (score 2):

You can define and override many config settings (like `become: false`) on per-play basis

For example:

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.1.2
  tasks:
  - name:  some task
    shell: foo

- hosts: 192.168.1.2
  become: false
  roles:  my_ssh_role
```

Answer (score 0):

I've founded something that works:

```
---
 - hosts: slaves
   strategy: free
#   connection: network_cli
   become: no
   roles:
      - ssh
 - name: import playbbok
   import_playbook: suite_config_linux.yml
```

I created an another playbook with `become: no` which call the ssh role and the second playbook with `import_playbook` ( `include` will disappear in 2.8 version of Ansible)

```
---
 - hosts: slaves
   strategy: free
#   connection: network_cli
   roles:
#      - ssh
      - proxy
      - vmware_tools
      - ntp
      - nmap
      - tcpdump
      - unattended-upgrades
      - traceroute
      - apache
      - mysql
```